# Python tkinter - How to resize widgets when user expands the windows

Tags: python, tkinter

I try to learn python and Tkinter and i have to develop a small user interface. Basically, there are 4 buttons in the screen and I put a LabelFrame to have all these buttons on a same label.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title('Example')

content=Frame(root)
myButtons=LabelFrame(content, text="My Buttons", padx=7, pady=7)

one = Button(myButtons, text="Button 1")
two = Button(myButtons, text="Button 2")
three = Button(myButtons, text="Button 3")
four = Button(myButtons, text="Button 4")

content.grid(column=0, row=0)
myButtons.grid(column=0, row=0)

one.grid(column=0, row=0)
two.grid(column=1, row=0)
three.grid(column=0, row=1)
four.grid(column=1, row=1)

root.mainloop()
```

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2eyu.png)

I would like buttons and the label to expand when the user expand the window.

I try to add

```
root.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(1,weight=1)
root.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
root.grid_rowconfigure(1,weight=1)
```

but it doens't work ...

Comment: You have to configure the weight for every widget that has children, that means both on the root window and on `myButtons`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Bryan mentioned in the comment, each parent widget object, needs to manage their children geometry. Your attempted solution doesn't work because geometry management done by `grid_rowconfigure` and `grid_columnconfigure` affect the very children of the widgets but not any grandchildren. Your `root` has only 1 widget object in its 1x1 grid. Which means that the configuration methods for `root` does essentially nothing if that grid index doesn't exist in the first place.

As your `root` has a 1x1 grid that has `content` in it.  Then your `content` has another 1x1 grid that has `myButtons` in it. Finally it has a 2x2 grid which has your buttons: `one`, `two`, `three`, `four`.

When you resize your `root` If you want your `content` to resize too, you need:

```
content.grid_configure(sticky="nsew")
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

But that only allows `content` Frame to resize, but not necessarily what's inside that. If you want to resize your `myButtons` with it you then need:

```
myButtons.grid_configure(sticky="nsew")
content.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
content.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

But again, that only allows you to resize your `myButtons` LabelFrame when its parent, `content`, resizes. It still won't let the children in `myButtons`; `one`, `two`, `three`, `four` to resize. You finally need to have:

```
one.grid_configure(sticky="nsew")
two.grid_configure(sticky="nsew")
three.grid_configure(sticky="nsew")
four.grid_configure(sticky="nsew")

myButtons.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
myButtons.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
myButtons.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
myButtons.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
```

Comment: Hello, thank for you answer but it didn't work, i put the detail above ...

Comment: @LocPhi try setting `sticky` options to `"nsew"` in all `grid` calls as in `content.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")` for example. Also you should rather edit your very question when there's such an update.

Comment: Thank you it works perfectly now when i change the window size.

Answer (score 1):

here is a function to do that automatically ...

```
def make_dynamic(widget):
    col_count,row_count = widget.grid_size()
    
    for i in range(row_count):
        widget.grid_rowconfigure(i, weight=1)

    for i in range(col_count):
        widget.grid_columnconfigure(i, weight=1)

    for child in widget.children.values():
        child.grid_configure(sticky="nsew")
        make_dynamic(child)
```

you just have to apply it to root and it ll take care of the rest

```
make_dynamic(root)
```